# How to use Filepond with PHP form and attach files with post

Tags: laravel, file-upload, filepond

I'm using Filepond with the Laravel framework.

I need to send a file related to an article.

**HTML code:**

```
<form action="submit.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
      <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="2" />
      <input type="file" class="filepond" name="filepond" data-max-files="1"/>
      <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit" class="btn btn-info" />
</form>

<script>
    // get a reference to the input element
    const inputElement = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');

    // create a FilePond instance at the input element location
    const pond = FilePond.create( inputElement, {
        maxFiles: 1,
        allowBrowse: false,
        instantUpload: false,
    });
</script>
```

How can I use the submit form button to download my files and get `$_POST['post_id']`?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately that's not possible on most browsers because the value of a file input field cannot be set.

To work around this limitation you can:

- Upload the file asynchronously (using the FilePond `server.process` property)
- Encode the file as base64 data (using the [FilePond encode plugin](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/plugins/file-encode/))
- Use a DataTransfer object to set the file input value (at the moment this only works on Chrome / Firefox)

For more information on the DataTransfer solution see:
https://pqina.nl/blog/the-trouble-with-editing-and-uploading-files-in-the-browser/

Answer (score 1):

While this question might be a bit dated, here's a response for developers currently encountering this issue.

I don't know why I saw a lot of people saying that this is not possible. There is a workaround without limitations. If you have data, you just want to put it somewhere else.

**Solution :**

1. In the form you want to submit create an input

   - If it's multiple make sure you put the brackets for the name

     ```
     <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple>
     ```
   - If it's not multiple

     ```
     <input type="file" id="files" name="files">
     ```
2. Create your pond instance

   ```
   const pond = FilePond.create(element);
   ```
3. Attach an event and call a function

   ```
   pond.on('addfile', (error, file) => {
    PutIntoInput();
   }
   ```
4. Create the function

   ```
   function PutIntoInput(){
       const filesFromPond = pond.getFiles(); // pond is your instance
       const filesInput = $('#files')[0]; // element we created in step1
       const newFileList = new DataTransfer(); // new file list
       filesFromPond.forEach(file => { // Add each file to a list
           newFileList.items.add(file.file);
       });
       filesInput.files = newFileList.files; // Set the file list
   }
   ```

PS : You might use CSS to hide the input type="file" because you cannot set it to hidden in this cas.